# neo4j query - can't combine node and relationship properties

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to combine the properties of a node with the properties of it's relationships while collecting them. But my attempt doesn't seem to work ...

my query looks like the following :

```
MATCH (foo:Foo)-[rel:Rel]->()
RETURN collect(properties(foo) + properties(rel)) as myCollection
```

EDIT :

I need a solution without the use of other plugins like APOC

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Properties() returns a map, not a collection, so you can't combine them in this way with Cypher.

You can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to combine two maps into one:

```
MATCH (foo:Foo)-[rel:Rel]->()
apoc.map.merge(properties(foo),properties(rel)) YIELD value
RETURN collect(value) as props
```

EDIT

As for approaches that don't use plugins, there are two that I know of using Map Projection, but they come with their own complications.

First, if you know all the properties you want to get, you can explicitly set them in the properties map using Map Projection:

```
MATCH (foo:Foo)-[rel:Rel]->()
RETURN foo {.*, relProp1:rel.prop1, relProp2:rel.prop2, relProp3:rel.prop3 ...} as props
```

Or, You can set the entire properties map, but it will be the value for a key, rather than a true combined map:

```
MATCH (foo:Foo)-[rel:Rel]->()
RETURN foo {.*, relProps:properties(rel)} as props
```

Comment: I actually just want to combine the properties into one object, like Object.assign(obj1, obj2, obj3) in javascript. I think APOC is not installed on default, this is sadly not working for me.

Comment: Yes, `apoc.map.merge()` will combine the properties maps of the node and the relationship into one object. If your MATCHes match on multiple objects (your example will match on all :Foo nodes and all :Rel relationships from each of those :Foo nodes) then the `collect()` at the end will end up giving you a collection of property maps for each :Foo / :Rel pair.

Comment: As for APOC, installation instructions are on the linked page. Basically you download the jar, drop the jar in the plugins folder, and restart Neo4j. Should be very quick.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do that currently. Maybe in Neo4j 3.2 later in the year.

Comment: I edited my answer with the only alternatives I know. Hope one of those works for you.

Comment: Thanks, for now I can use APOC Procedures. But I sadly can't use the alternatives